# Creating a line diff with isomorphic-git

Tags: javascript, git, isomorphic-javascript

I am trying to get output from [isomorphic-git](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git) that is similar to `git diff` for a GitHub action.

I took a look at the `map` function on the `git.walk` implementation in isomorphic-git [here](https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/walk#mapstring-array-walkerentry-null-promise-any) but I'm having trouble using it.

I'm successfully able to walk the tree using the following code:

```
async function main() {
  const ref = 'HEAD'
  const trees = [git.TREE({ref}), git.WORKDIR()]
  const walk = await git.walk({
    fs,
    dir: '.github',
    trees,
    map: (filepath, [workdir, tree]) => [filepath, !!workdir, !!tree]
  })

  console.log(walk)
}

main()
```

How can I improve the `map` function here and use [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) to output the changes in the files between my current worktree and `HEAD` to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example code on performing a git diff on the isomorphic-git code snippets page.

https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/snippets#git-diff-name-status-commithash1-commithash2

The result looks like this:

```
[
  { path: '/.gitignore', type: 'equal' },
  { path: '/package.json', type: 'modify' },
]
```

For each file, it generates the oid

```
        const Aoid = await A.oid()
        const Boid = await B.oid()
```

With those, I believe you can use the readObject method to get the content to diff.

https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/readObject